# Importing a module from elsewhere in directory

Tags: python

I have seen many attempts at answering this, but none have successfully aided in all instances for me. My directory looks like the following:

```
folder1
   -file1.py
   -folder2
      -file2.py
```

I have attempted the following from many SO answers, in `file2.py`:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '.../folder1/file1.py')
from file1 import funx
```

This worked when file2 was above file1 in the hierarchy or if they are in the same folder, but with the above hierarchy I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Any help in resolving this would be very useful? I am mostly interested to see if there is a way to have the module be in a place where it can be called just like other python modules (`sklearn`, `pandas`, etc.) regardless of location in my directory. Thanks!

Comment: read https://leemendelowitz.github.io/blog/how-does-python-find-packages.html

Comment: how you're executing the code? You can do `from ..file1 import funx` but your code need to be in a package

Comment: `sys.path(1, '.../folder1/file1.py')` makes no sense because `sys.path` is not callable.

Comment: Why not set the PYTHONPATH environment variable to the parent of folder1 and then anyone can write: `from folder1 import file1` or `from folder1.folder2 import file2`.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson was a typo. See edit

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a module for global access--
In console--

`$python`

```
$python
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
```

The output may look like -

`C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages` -- in Windows

or

`/usr/bin/python2.7/site-packages` -- in mac

Copy the file you want to have global access to this location.

In your program you can import file directly like---

```
from file1 import funx
```